# tcolorbox: raster before/after skip do not seem to work

Tags: tcolorbox

Here is a MWE.

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,raster,breakable,} 



\begin{tcolorbox}%
[%
    boxrule=2mm,%
    colback=lightcyan,%
    colframe=red,%
    title=TITLE,%
]%
\begin{tcbraster}%
[%Begin description raster
    raster columns=1,%
    raster force size=false,%
%Affects all tcboxes    
    raster before skip=0mm,% 240 Does not seem to work.
    raster row skip=0mm,% 240
    raster after skip=0mm,% 240 Does not seem to work.
    raster left skip=-2mm,% 240
    raster right skip=-2mm,% 240
]%End description raster
\begin{tcolorbox}% Box 1
[%Begin description Box 1
    enhanced,show bounding box,%comment to prevent the bndbox from showing
    unbreakable,%
    colback= white,%
    colframe= blue,%
    boxrule=0.2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    sidebyside,%
        lower separated=true,
        sidebyside gap=3mm,%
        sidebyside align=top seam,%
        width=(\linewidth),%. 
        lefthand width=75mm,%107
%       righthand width=60mm,%107
        left skip =-5mm,%
        right skip =-9mm,%
    left=0mm,%
    right=0mm,%
    top=0mm,%
    bottom=0mm,%
]%End description Box 1
Text 1 left  Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left 
    \tcblower
Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right 
\end{tcolorbox}%Box 1
%%
\begin{tcolorbox}% Box 2
[%Begin description Box 2
    enhanced,show bounding box,%comment to prevent the bndbox from showing
    unbreakable,%
    colback= white,%
    colframe= blue,%
    boxrule=0.2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    sidebyside,%
        lower separated=true,
        sidebyside gap=3mm,%
        sidebyside align=top seam,%
        width=(\linewidth),%
%       lefthand width=40mm,%107
        righthand width=80mm,%107   
        left skip =-5mm, %.
        right skip =-9mm, %.
    left=0mm,%
    right=0mm,%
    top=0mm,%
    bottom=0mm,%
]%End description Box 5
Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left 
    \tcblower
Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right 
\end{tcolorbox}%Box 2
\end{tcbraster}%End Raster
\end{tcolorbox}
```

In general, the commands tend not to be independent but here I have not been able to determine what is preventing the space between the TITLE and the first box and the space between the second box and the bottom of the main box from being 0. The other `raster skip`s, including `raster row skip` work as they are supposed to:

[image: png of MWE]

(Notes: The numbers in the comments are the page numbers in the doc. The bounding boxes can be made not to show by commenting the corresponding lines.)

Comment: You are aware that your document is by no means 'm' nor 'w' ? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer 'm' I think It was, 'w' it certainly was not because I had lifted it from a file that worked with a separate preamble. I realized that in the middle of last night. Really! Sorry about that. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what is done for the inner boxes in the raster has to be done for the outer box: `top=0pt` etc, and in addition the `nobeforeafter` option for the inner boxes must be activated to eliminate any vertical spacing.

However, there should be a better organization of the box settings, i.e. with a style or a special `\newtcolorbox` definition for this!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,raster,breakable,} 


\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}%
[%
    boxrule=2mm,%
    colback=cyan,%
    colframe=red,%
    title=TITLE,%
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
]%
\begin{tcbraster}%
[%Begin description raster
    raster columns=1,%
    raster force size=false,%
%Affects all tcboxes    
    raster before skip=0mm,% 240 Does not seem to work.
    raster row skip=0mm,% 240
    raster after skip=0mm,% 240 Does not seem to work.
    raster left skip=-2mm,% 240
    raster right skip=-2mm,% 240
]%End description raster
\begin{tcolorbox}% Box 1
[%Begin description Box 1
    enhanced,show bounding box,%comment to prevent the bndbox from showing
    unbreakable,%
    colback= white,%
    colframe= blue,%
    boxrule=0.2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    sidebyside,%
    nobeforeafter,
        lower separated=true,
        sidebyside gap=3mm,%
        sidebyside align=top seam,%
        width=(\linewidth),%. 
        lefthand width=75mm,%107
%       righthand width=60mm,%107
        left skip =-4mm,
        right skip =-8mm,%
    left=0mm,%
    right=0mm,%
    top=0mm,%
    bottom=0mm%
]%End description Box 1
Text 1 left  Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left 
    \tcblower
Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right 
\end{tcolorbox}%Box 1
%%
\begin{tcolorbox}% Box 2
[%Begin description Box 2
    enhanced,show bounding box,%comment to prevent the bndbox from showing
    unbreakable,%
    colback= white,%
    colframe= blue,%
    boxrule=0.2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    sidebyside,%
    nobeforeafter,
        lower separated=true,
        sidebyside gap=3mm,%
        sidebyside align=top seam,%
        width=(\linewidth),%
%       lefthand width=40mm,%107
        righthand width=80mm,%107   
        left skip =-4mm, %.
        right skip =-8mm, %.
    left=0mm,%
    right=0mm,%
    top=0mm,%
    bottom=0mm,%
]%End description Box 5
Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left 
    \tcblower
Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right 
\end{tcolorbox}%Box 2
\end{tcbraster}%End Raster
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

A better style, in my point of view:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
    \tcbuselibrary{skins,raster,breakable,} 


\begin{document}


\makeatletter


\newlength{\leftshift}
\newlength{\rightshift}

\newcommand{\determineshifts}{%
  \global\leftshift=-\kvtcb@leftupper
  \global\rightshift=-8mm
}


\tcbset{%
  boxcommonstyle/.style={%
    enhanced,show bounding box,%comment to prevent the bndbox from showing
    unbreakable,%
    colback= white,%
    colframe= blue,%
    boxrule=0.2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    sidebyside,%
    nobeforeafter,
    lower separated=true,
    sidebyside gap=3mm,%
    sidebyside align=top seam,%
    width=(\linewidth),%
    left skip=\leftshift,
    right skip=\rightshift,%
    left=0mm,%
    right=0mm,%
    top=0mm,%
    bottom=0mm,%
  },
  boxstyle1/.style={%
    boxcommonstyle,
    lefthand width=75mm,%107
  },
  boxstyle2/.style={%
    boxcommonstyle,
    righthand width=80mm,%107   
  },
  outerboxstyle/.style={%
    boxrule=2mm,%
    colback=cyan,%
    colframe=red,%
    title=TITLE,%
    top=0pt,
    outer arc=\kvtcb@bottom@rule@stand,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt
  }
}




\newtcolorbox{topbox}[1][]{%
  code={\determineshifts},
  boxstyle1,
  #1
}

\newtcolorbox{bottombox}[1][]{%
  code={\determineshifts},
  boxstyle2,
  #1,
}

\makeatother


\begin{tcolorbox}[outerboxstyle]
\begin{tcbraster}%
[%Begin description raster
    raster columns=1,%
    raster force size=false,%
%Affects all tcboxes    
    raster before skip=0mm,% 240 Does not seem to work.
    raster row skip=0mm,% 240
    raster after skip=0mm,% 240 Does not seem to work.
    raster left skip=-2mm,% 240
    raster right skip=-2mm,% 240
]%End description raster
\begin{topbox}
Text 1 left  Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left Text 1 left 
    \tcblower
Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right Text 1 right 
\end{topbox}%
%%
\begin{bottombox}%
Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left Text  2 left 
    \tcblower
Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right Text 2 right 
\end{bottombox}%
\end{tcbraster}%End Raster
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second version corrects the style and the `arc` arrow by the overshooting lower box

Comment: It worked. As for the style, it was part of the 'm' aspect and I agree that it is very ugly. The actual box is a bit better. Or so I hope. I will post a link when I have ported your correction to the magnum opus. (But I will study your second version before the port.) Thanks again.

Comment: @schremmer: Apart from my solution: A `\tcbset{foo/.style=....}` is in most cases a good idea as well as specialized `\newtcolorbox` boxes

Comment: Actually, I have been using many `\newtcolorbox`boxes and I want to do a `\tcbset` for each one. Right now, though, I still have a problem with the above: in the case of a `page break`, I got an artifact between the inner boxes across the break. See the "Work Zone" in 6.pdf at (http://freemathtexts.org/InProgress/RAFv7.1/)

Comment: @schremmer: That's possible a result of being a nested box -- those aren't breakable really

Comment: The artifacts are _between_ the two inner boxes which are in fact unbreakable.

Comment: Found what the "artifacts" are: Even though the other boxes are tight against each other, there is a small space below the box at the bottom of the page and another small space above the box at the top of the next page. The "artifacts" then are pieces of the frame of the outer box that show in those spaces. (A bug?) Other than that, all is fine.

Comment: @schremmer: Perhaps it's the `\interlineskip`